# fadeIn and fadeOut effect between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout, jquery-effects

I'm trying to make some transition effects for my page.

The goal is to fade in the page when you first enter, and then when you click a link, the page will fadeout and fadein the destination page. But It won't get the destination url so when i click a link, the url changes to *www.example.com/#undefined*

Any suggestions?

```
jQuery.holdReady(true);
jQuery("body").css("opacity", 0);
jQuery.holdReady(false);
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("body").fadeTo(1500, 1);
    $(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("body").fadeTo(1500, 0, function () {
            // get the href attribute
            var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");

            // veryfy if the new url exists or is a hash
            if (!newUrl || newUrl[0] === "#") {
                // set that hash
                location.hash = newUrl;
                return;
            }

            // now, fadeout the html (whole page)
            $("body").fadeTo(1500, 1, function () {
                // when the animation is complete, set the new location
                location = newUrl;
            });
            // prevent the default browser behavior.
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: $(this).attr("href"); is probably referencing to the body, not the "a", so it does not have href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the inner function, `this` doesn't point at the `<a>` element that was clicked.  Move the resolution of `newUrl` outside of that function:

```
jQuery.holdReady(true);
jQuery("body").css("opacity", 0);
jQuery.holdReady(false);
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("body").fadeTo(1500, 1);
    $(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {

        // get the href attribute
        // "this" is still the <a> element here
        var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");

        event.preventDefault();
        $("body").fadeTo(1500, 0, function () {

            //here, where you were trying to get the url, "this"
            //points to the animated element, ie body


            // veryfy if the new url exists or is a hash
            if (!newUrl || newUrl[0] === "#") {
                // set that hash
                location.hash = newUrl;
                return;
            }

            //just update the location without fading in at this point
            location = newUrl;

            // prevent the default browser behavior.
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice:D It returns the correct url :) So far so good. But it act strange. it fades out and fadein, and then it changes to the new page.

Comment: I don't think you need the inner `fadeTo` - will edit my answer.

Comment: That removed the fade-in before the actuel page shift, but I can't wrap my head around getting a fadeIn effect on initial page load, and a fadein when you enter another page.

Comment: The other page would have to be responsible for its own fade in, unless you start to look at dynamically replacing the content on the existing page, but that's a different thing entirely to what you're doing here

Comment: I made it work. I had the script before </body>... The fadein from the first lines work now. Thanks for your help! Is there a way to avoid page flicker? When I enter contact page via link on index, I see a the page for 1 second and then it fades in. Is this a bug?

Comment: It's likely you see it before jquery kicks in and sets the opacity to 0.  You could do that in css yourself without using javascript, but then you run the risk of it never appearing for people with javascript disabled

Comment: Ye that would be very anti Progressive enshancement :P

Hmmm. The flicker effect only appears in Chrome and Opera, not in Safari, firefox or IE :/

Comment: I added opacity: 0; to the body tag and made a noscript tag in the head with: body { opacity: 1 !important; }

Seems to work now:) Shows the page with JS is disabled aswell.

Thanks a lot for your inputs!